# How to get the datatype of value entered by User

Tags: c#

Eg:`TableName.ColumnName==Value`.

I have the datatype of the `columnName` but the value is entered by the user,
which can be int/string/datetime or any value.

I need to check the datatype of columnName and value.The code should work for both windows
and web application

Comment: Any time a user types a value into a textbox it will always be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the user tells you what the data type is, you will only be able to determine it by trying to parse it to different types, and even then you are not guaranteed to get it right.

Using the different `TryParse` methods that are defined on the `int`, `double`, `DateTime` and other types in the BCL you can see if the passed in string is parseable to one of more of these types.

At this point you will need to decide which type you want to use... Since you already know the datatype of the column, you can test to see if you can parse to that type and if not, reject the input.

In all cases, the value will be a valid string (as entered by the user), as this is the type of the `Text` property of all controls.

Comment: @oded..Its true that the value entered by the user is got as string due to the Text property.I just wanted to make a client side validation to alert the user about the wrong value passed for the filter Criteria. Will try parsing to the column type.

Comment: @psobhan - You can look at [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) to help out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( Value is string)
  //code to handle
else if (value is int)
//code to handle
```

etc.

Comment: @Wegged-Since the value is got from the textbox, the datatype is always string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you come up with the way how to recognize the entered value is int, string or datetime, there is no other way. As I understand user enters the string always.
I would use RegEx maybe??? if you are quite clear how date-times / int / string differ from each-other.

Comment: @Tengiz-maybe I could used regEx to avoid spl characters.

Comment: Actually, if the case is related exactly to these 3: int/string/datetime, life can be much easier if you use RegEx. At least they differ by their content definitely. And what are spl chars?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I'm guessing that your talking about casting a variable to specific type.

In your case, say TableName.ColumnName is an integer, you would do something like this:

```
string valueByUser = "23"; // Wherever this comes from.

int number = 0;

int.TryParse(valueByUser, out number);

TableName.ColumnName = number;
```

Since you will know what the data type of ColumnName is, you can use the appropriate TryParse to conver the value e.g.

```
decimal.TryParse()
DateTime.TryParse()
```

Comment: @Jason-will try to parse the value based on the column type.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving an answer on how to solve the specific issue at hand, it seems it could be avoided altogether by making a better design decision on how users input values into that field.

You say `columName` has a specific datatype but you are allowing the user to input any value in the presentation layer? This seems to have a code smell.

Can you not enforce some form of validation at the UI layer. I can't think of any instances where I would allow a user to input any value into field that should conform to a specific datatype. I'd validate the input based on the chosen `columnName` type.

Comment: @cpedros-I really didn't mean that columnName have a specific type. Itz that I can get the datatype of columns(based on the column name) selected by the user. It it the fault of the user to select column of type 'int' and try to check it with string value.but wanted a simple method to avoid exception by preventing it from the first stage itseft.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
 private string ParseString(string str)
        {

            bool boolValue;
            Int32 intValue;
            Int64 bigintValue;
            decimal doubleValue;
            DateTime dateValue;

            // Place checks higher in if-else statement to give higher priority to type.

            if (bool.TryParse(str, out boolValue))
                return "System_Boolean";
            else if (Int32.TryParse(str, out intValue))
                return "System_Int32";
            else if (Int64.TryParse(str, out bigintValue))
                return "System_Int64";
            else if (decimal.TryParse(str, out doubleValue))
                return "System_Decimal";
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateValue))
                return "System_DateTime";
            else return "System_String";

        }
```